# Crash on Float to Int conversion

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, int

I'm getting a random crash on my live app on Float to Int conversion line.

I can't figure out why it's crashing and can't reproduce it as it's random crash on live app. Any suggestion on how to fix crash?

Crash log

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  MyApp                0x100703778 closure #1 in MyViewController.getBalance(isRefreshed:) + 797 (MyViewController.swift:797)
1  MyApp                0x1005c7670 closure #1 in closure #1 in fetchtBalance(completed:) + 185 (Utils.swift:185)
2  MyApp                0x10051ab10 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4335790864 (<compiler-generated>:4335790864)
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1ae908b7c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1ae909fd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1ae915cc8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 968
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1aebdee0c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1aebd9b68 __CFRunLoopRun + 1980
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1aebd9084 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
9  GraphicsServices               0x1b8e27534 GSEventRunModal + 108
10 UIKitCore                      0x1b2d49670 UIApplicationMain + 1940
11 MyApp                0x1004ec6b8 main + 20 (ClientMyProfileViewController.swift:20)
12 libdyld.dylib                  0x1aea58e18 start + 4
```

Code

```
import UIKit

var balance: String!
var cost: String?

func getBalance () {
    fetchBalance() { (result, error) in
        guard let balanceFloatValue = Float(balance!) else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        guard let costFloat = Float(cost!) else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        let costPerSec = costFloat / 60

        let talkTime = balanceFloatValue / costPerSec

        let talkTimeInt = Int(talkTime) // Line No. 797  Crash here

        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: you should show us the error as well, chances are the error is not there, your code is not crashing with those values.

Comment: Aside from the fact that putting `calculate()` in your file like that won't compile this seems fine.  Running this in a Playground (and putting `calculate()` *after* the declaration of the function) works.  The potential crash that I see is if you switch the operands in `talkTime` as you will get a "divide by zero" error.

Comment: Try to avoid force unwrap optional may help in this case

Comment: I've updated crash log from crashlytics. The function and line number is the line which I've commented in my snippet.

Comment: @Tieda Wei please elaborate.

Comment: @creeperspeak if it was divide by 0 error it should happen in the line above last line. Crash happens in last line.

Comment: the error is just not in that part of the code. we need more info to find the error, the full error message would help us to at least check if it has anything to do with that particular part of the code. Can't you paste the whole error message? if it's only on live app, cant you log the values? Log the stacktrace as well.

Comment: I've updated full crashlog and code.

Comment: Can you show us full utils.swift and full MyViewController.swift (i assume you are already showing us your full MyViewController but i might be wrong)

Comment: @Nero I've checked and I don't think there is any other part of code which may be affecting crash showing on line number 797. Utils:fetchBalance function calls API to get value and returns via completion().

Comment: Assuming that's an accurate line, it must have somehow gotten a talkTime of inf, nan, or something outside of the range that's representable by Int.  But without knowing more, not much can be said.  If you can't figure out how those might happen, you may have to test for those cases and log the results if the Int() will fail.

Comment: On a side note: don't use `Float` for currencies. These are the kinds of issues you'll run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause for this error is the values themselves

```
let a:Float = 9999999999999999999999.9
let b = "0.000000000000000000001"
let c:Float = a/Float(b)!
let x = Int(c)  // <- Crash here
```

0/0 will make you crash in: let c:Float = a/Float(b)! so thats not it, but anything else that can make talkTime outside of a Int will make you crash
This would also explain why you only encounter the error randomly since its only for values that make that division NaN or inf or something outside the int like bg2b said

Comment: You may be right as I can't think of anything else. I'm assuming I've to check the talkTime for isNaN?

Comment: you should check for NaN , talkTime should be smaller than Int.Max and bigger than Int.Min too

Comment: Ok will do, tx for help.

Comment: This is WRONG:
Int(talkTime) ?? 0 
this way you can stop the crash with a default value (if the cast fails it will use the 0 or whatever value you use there)
Forget about this

Comment: Int(talkTime) ?? 0 gives warning which is obvious. => Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'Int', so the right side is never used.

Comment: haha yah i was editing it b4 your comment, nvm that it does not help you at all, you just need to check the values you are getting

Comment: if(! talkTime.isInfinite && ! talkTime.isNaN){
    let talkTimeInt = Int(talkTime)
}
this is how it should be done haha, you can set a default value or do whatever you need to do for invalid ints in the else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are force unwrapping the balance value. Try to unwrap the converted value like: „Float(balance)!“